# Send multiple chechbox values with different class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi making a live filter function, but having a problem to send checkbox values from different classes:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return test();" class="type" name="type1" value="1"  /> Trousers <br />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return test();" class="type" name="type3" value="3"  /> T-shirts <br />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return test();" class="type" name="type2" value="2"  /> Jackets <br />

<input type="checkbox" onclick="return test();" class="color" name="color1" value="1"  /> Red <br />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return test();" class="color" name="color3" value="3"  /> Blue <br />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return test();" class="color" name="color2" value="2"  /> Green <br />
```

With this code I'm able to get values dynamicaly from all checkboxes:

```
function test() {
    var counter = 0, 
        i = 0,       
        url = 'items.php?',    
        input_obj = $('input[type=checkbox]');


    for (i = 0; i < input_obj.length; i++) {
        if (input_obj[i].type === 'checkbox' && input_obj[i].checked === true) {
            counter++;
            url = url + '&a=' + input_obj[i].value;
        }
    }
    if (counter > 0) {
        alert(url);

    }
}
```

But I need that different class have different url name `(type - &a=value, color - &b=value)` and combine all this to one url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group the checkboxes by giving them the same **name** (end that name with `[]` since you are using PHP), not by using classes. Then use [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to generate the encoded data for your Ajax request.

For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dWS6P/):

```
<form>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="1"  /> Trousers </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="3"  /> T-shirts </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="2"  /> Jackets </label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="1"  /> Red </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="3"  /> Blue </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="2"  /> Green </label>

</form>
```

​
and

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this.form).serialize());
});​
```

Comment: Using the well known "<var name>[]" naming style for checkboxes and transferring that as part of a get url actually violates the url syntax. It works in all browsers, but it does not conform to the standard...

Comment: @arkascha — Which part of the URL syntax does it violate?

Comment: urls like this are actually invalid, in a strict sense: http://<server>/path/script?var[]=hello. You can encode the "[]" into percent notation (which makes the url valid again). But then it depends on the server side setup if that works as expected.

Comment: @arkascha — Since browsers that submit forms and jQuery when you call `serialize()` encode the `[]` characters, that doesn't matter. As for the server side of things, that just depends on the code parsing the URI to not be broken (and the code PHP uses internally isn't).

Comment: @arkascha — Since it *is* encoded, it is valid, no "again" about it. The op mentioned PHP in their source code, and I mentioned it in my answer when I said `[]` was needed because the op was using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Took a while to understand what you are trying to express...

I *guess* you want to send the current state of the checkboxes to one url, most likely as soon as some checkbox is chosen.

I don't really understand how that mechanism works with all the onclick's...
I suggest you restructure your code:

Drop those onclick definitions from your input checkboxes and instead bind your test() routine to a javascript event that is raised when a checkbox is clicked. Using a javascript library like jQuery makes this more convenient. Using different jQuery selectors for the bind you can have different reactions on different events, for example filter by the class of the checkbox checked.

```
$('input.type').on('click',function(e){test('type',e);});
$('input.color').on('click',function(e){test('color',e);});
```

Alternatively you can use a single bind and evaluate the event handed over as parameter "e". You can use it to read the class of the element that has been clicked.

Hope this helps. Otherwise try to make more clear what you actually want to happen. Your goal is not that " different classes have a different url name", but something like the checkbox values should be sent to different urls, or the browser should be forwardeed to different urls, depending on...

Comment: Yes you are right. I need to send all checkbox values to other page instantly after checkbox is selected like `items.php?a=1&b=2` if I uncheck first check box it should look `items.php?b=2`